# swift: in-app purchases prices in my dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have two in-app purchases in my application. And I want to load my in-app purchases prices.

I use this code to load prices:

```
let productIds = Set(["purchase","purchase1"])
var products = [String:SKProduct]()
var price = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if !(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchased")){
            if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
                let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIds);
                productsRequest.delegate = self;
                productsRequest.start();
                print("Fetching Products");
            } else {
                print("Can't make purchases");
            }
        }

    }

func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    for product in response.products {
        self.products[product.productIdentifier] = product

        price[product.productIdentifier] = localizedPriceForProduct(product)
        print(price)
    }
}

func localizedPriceForProduct(_ product:SKProduct) -> String {
    let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    priceFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4
    priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    return priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)!
}
```

But in `price` I to get this result

```
["purchase": "3,00 USD"]
["purchase": "3,00 USD", "purchase1": "1,00 USD"]
```

But I need to get this:

```
["purchase": "3,00 USD", "purchase1": "1,00 USD"]
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing within the for loop, so your code is correct, just the print is in the incorrect line.

Try:

```
for product in response.products {
    self.products[product.productIdentifier] = product

    price[product.productIdentifier] = localizedPriceForProduct(product)
}
print(price)
```